# Что не так с setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести окно через 5 секунд. Не совсем понятно, почему ниже приведенный код не работает:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-example')
setTimeout(() => {}, 5000);
```

Comment: А что означает «не работает»? Он же ничего и не делает у вас?

Comment: В конце 1-й строчки не хватает ";" ну и setTimeout ничего не делает, правда... Там должно быть что-то вроде setTimeout(function(){ modal.style.display = 'block'}, 5000); , к примеру.

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout(функция/код, задержка в миллисекундах);

```js
function func() {
  alert( 'Привет' );
}

setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

Вот вам с примером alert выведется через 1 секунду

Comment: Это я понимаю, а как мне вызов блока по идентификатору задержать?

Comment: можешь дать ссылку на часть кода который тебе нужно отредактировать с setTimeout я с радостью тебе помогу. На словах я немного не понимаю

Comment: Окей. Есть окно div id=modal-example, после 5 секунд с момента загрузки сайта мне нужно его показать. Вот и все

Comment: HTML
<div id="modal-example">This text is displayed after 3 seconds</div>
CSS
div#modal-example{
 visibility: hidden;
}
JS
var doc = document.getElementById('modal-example');
setTimeout(func,3000);
function func(){
doc.style.visibility = "visible";
}

Comment: Спасибо, это мой прокол. Ссылка на попап вида <a href="#modal-example" uk-toggle>Go</a>, и я забыл про uk-toggle, а сам по себе modal-example пустой, ни дисплей нон, ни виз хайд не прописаны там. Вообще теперь хз

Comment: добавляй id тегу а и просто измени первую строку js где я получал элемент по id

Comment: Немного не понял..

Comment: <a href="#modal-example" uk-toggle id="test">Go</a>
CSS div#test{ visibility: hidden; } 
JS var doc = document.getElementById('test'); setTimeout(func,3000); function func(){ doc.style.visibility = "visible"; }

Comment: Просто прикрути id

Comment: Вообще не то, мы не через кнопку вызываем вовсе. Ладно, разберусь. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Хорошо, не за что)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.modal-example {display: none;}
</style>
<div class="modal-example"></div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-example');
setTimeout(function(){modal.style.display = 'block';}, 5000);
</script>
```